# Cant' delete entries in solr 7.7.x with curl after upgrading from 5.x

Tags: solr

I upgraded solr to the latest 7.x version and now my application seems not to remove entries via curl anymore.

Original request:

```
curl_request("http://".SOLR_SERVER_USERNAME.":".SOLR_SERVER_PASSWORD."@".SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME.":".SOLR_SERVER_PORT."/".SOLR_SERVER_PATH."/update?stream.body=<delete><query>id:".$cl_active['id']."</query></delete>&commit=true");
```

results in :

```
http://rex:8983/solr/findix/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3Eid:978382%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E&commit=true
```

Response:

> // 20190329102610 //
>   http://rex:8983/solr/findix/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3Eid:978382%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E&commit=true
>
> {   "error": {
>       "metadata": [
>         "error-class",
>         "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
>         "root-error-class",
>         "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"
>       ],
>       "msg": "Stream Body is disabled. See http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/requestdispatcher-in-solrconfig.html
>   for help",
>       "code": 400   } }

Therefore I altered it as found [in this answer at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405333/org-apache-solr-common-solrexception-stream-body-is-disabled):

```
update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>id:978388</query></delete>'
```

like this:
    curl_request("http://".SOLR_SERVER_USERNAME.":".SOLR_SERVER_PASSWORD."@".SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME.":".SOLR_SERVER_PORT."/".SOLR_SERVER_PATH."/update?commit=true -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' --data-binary 'id:".$cl_active['id']."'");

results in:

```
http://rex:8983/solr/findix/update?commit=true%20-H%20%27Content-Type:%20text/xml%27%20--data-binary%20%27%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3Eid:978384%3C/delete%3E%27
```

Response:

> // 20190329102745 //
>   http://rex:8983/solr/findix/update?commit=true%20-H%20%27Content-Type:%20text/xml%27%20--data-binary%20%27%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3Eid:978384%3C/delete%3E%27
>
> {   "responseHeader": {
>       "status": 0,
>       "QTime": 0   } }

What is wrong with the altered request, and how can I delete entries from the index via curl now?

Edited Question with suggestion for curl via PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://".SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME.":".SOLR_SERVER_PORT."/".SOLR_SERVER_PATH."/update?commit=true");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD , "".SOLR_SERVER_USERNAME.":".SOLR_SERVER_PASSWORD."");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "<delete><query>id:".$cl_active['id']."</query></delete>");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

# this is your XML as given in your example above (i.e. <delete>...)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Response

```
<lst name="responseHeader">   <int name="status">400</int>   <int name="QTime">0</int> </lst> <lst name="error">   <lst name="metadata">
    <str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
    <str name="root-error-class">com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException</str>   </lst>   <str name="msg">Unexpected EOF in prolog  at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]</str>   <int name="code">400</int> </lst> </response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `curl` parameters are indented to be used with the *command line* version of curl. In your case you'll have to modify the `curl_request` method to set the appropriate headers and POST data for your request.

In PHP you can do this through `curl_setopt` (or with `curl_setopt_array`):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '... .path ...');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

# this is your XML as given in your example above (i.e. <delete>...)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is needed? If I enter the URL above into a browser I get the response as indicated. I also now tried to implement your suggestion, but it is not clear to me where to add the delete option. Previously there was a stream.body=<query. What is the variable for your suggestion? I have altered the question with the curl commands filled out.

Comment: With curl_setopt I do get another error, something else must be wrong.

Comment: If you have _two identical_ calls with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` as in your example above, the second call will overwrite the version from the first.